# The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Tags: python, compiler-errors, aptana

I am new to python, I have a windows 7 64 bit OS. I installed Python 3.5.1 64  and Aptana Studio 3 and made sure that Aptana see the python interpreter by going to window -> preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter -> Python Interpreter -> New and I added all the required files.

Now, I am trying some scripts written from a book in a single python file through the Aptana Studio 3, whenever I press the run button, it keeps giving me this message:

"The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches".

I tried going to window -> preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Launch operations -> selected launch the selected resource or active editor

I tried promoting the file into a project, and it did not work. it just kept asking me for java script and installing firefox!!

I am new to python, I open aptana, and copy/paste some code in a new file, save it and try to run it to learn the language, that's all.

Is there a problem doing this without creating a project?

Any idea how to fix this error?